# How to make partial match in 2 ranges?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a formula `in Excel 2019` to do exact and partial matches in 2 databases for about 3000 rows, searching first in database1 (exact and best matching about 3k rows) and if not found, search in database2 (exact and best matching 2.5k rows). If not found show "Not found"

I use `INDEX(...MATCH(...))` to look for exact matches but don't know how to do partial matches.

The partial match should show the "best match", this is select the number that has more numbers in common in same order from left to right. In other words, select the number that
shares the longest common prefix. The minimun prefix length to match would be 4 digits, if only match 3 digits or none show "NOT FOUND".

**Examples:**

For number 50660000 in G2, the more similar numbers in column E are 5067000,5063005,506600002 and within these 3, the more similar is 506600002 because shares common
prefix of length 8.

**50660000**

**50660000**2

For number 3520913 in G6, the more similar numbers in column B are 352021,352621,352091000 and within these 3, the more similar is 352091000 because shares common
prefix of length 6.
3520913
352091000

For number 13603399617 in D9, the more similar numbers in column E are 1360339,136033 and within these 2, the more similar is 1360339 because shares common prefix of length 7.

**1360339**9617

**1360339**

For number 32486 in G7, the more similar number in column E is 32475 but only has the first 3 numbers in common, so show "NOT FOUND"

**324**86

**324**75

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **DATABASE 1** |  |  | **DATABASE 2** |  |
| 2 | **CODE** | **NUMBER** |  | **CODE** | **NUMBER** |
| 3 | XZS67 | 467275799 |  | XZS90 | 5067000 |
| 4 | XZS68 | 26879 |  | XZS78 | 5063005 |
| 5 | XZS69 | 26876 |  | XZS76 | 506600002 |
| 6 | XZS70 | 24825 |  | XZS29 | 32475 |
| 7 | XZS71 | 24826 |  | XZS39 | 4206080055 |
| 8 | XZS72 | 9639310 |  | XZS64 | 420602 |
| 9 | XZS73 | 9639311 |  | XZS35 | 42379 |
| 10 | XZS74 | 96393111 |  | XZS13 | 4237800 |
| 11 | XZS75 | 1246253 |  | XZS96 | 4237807672 |
| 12 | XZS76 | 1268789 |  | XZS16 | 42397030 |
| 13 | XZS77 | 1345990 |  | XZS05 | 5257000 |
| 14 |  |  |  | XZS47 | 421903 |
| 15 |  |  |  | XZS15 | 421905 |
| 16 |  |  |  | XZS40 | 4206020899 |
| 17 |  |  |  | XZS56 | 18072141180 |
| 18 |  |  |  | XZS03 | 18072144650 |
| 19 |  |  |  | XZS27 | 1809859 |
| 20 |  |  |  | XZS99 | 1360339 |
| 21 |  |  |  | XZS41 | 136033 |
| 22 |  |  |  | XZS98 | 1802692 |
| 23 |  |  |  | XZS60 | 180825 |
| 24 |  |  |  | XZS93 | 393533000 |
| 25 |  |  |  | XZS58 | 3932059 |
| 26 |  |  |  | XZS31 | 393205800448 |
| 27 |  |  |  | XZS89 | 352021 |
| 28 |  |  |  | XZS46 | 352621 |
| 29 |  |  |  | XZS71 | 352091000 |

Below the expected output.

```
In H2: =INDEX($A$3:$A$13,MATCH(G2,$B$3:$B$13,0))  --> Exact match formula to search in DB1
In I2: =INDEX($D$3:$D$30,MATCH(G2,$E$3:$E$30,0))  --> Exact match formula to search in DB2
```

The values in yellow are partial matches
[image]
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could try this formula : `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$13,MATCH(G2&"*",$B$3:$B$13&"",0)),INDEX($D$3:$D$30,MATCH(G2&"*",$E$3:$E$30&"",0)))`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried and shows correct output but is not showing the output for all cases, for example it shows #N/A for G3,G6,G12,G13

Comment: What would be expected output in case `42378` and why?

Comment: The output in case 42378 would be XZS13, because the more similar numbers are 4237800 and 4237807672, but 4237800 is the shortest one. If the options have the same length, the number to select could be the first in order of appearance, i.e 4237800 and 4237803 are the options but 4237800 appears first, select it. Hope make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [array formulae](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) below produce the expected results for your sample:
[image: screenshot illustrating result of using suggested array formulae]

The array formula in H2 is

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$13,MEDIAN(IFERROR(FIND(TRANSPOSE(MID(G2,1,LEN(G2)+4-ROW(A$4:INDEX(A:A,LEN(G2))))),$B$3:$B$13,1)*(ROW($B$3:$B$13)-2),"")))
```

(which is then copied down to H13)

and the array formula in I2 is

```
=INDEX($D$3:$D$30,MEDIAN(IFERROR(FIND(TRANSPOSE(MID(G2,1,LEN(G2)+4-ROW(A$4:INDEX(A:A,LEN(G2))))),$E$3:$E$30,1)*(ROW(($E$3:$E$30))-2),"")))
```

(which is then copied down to I13)

The regular formula in J2 is simply

```
=IFERROR(H2,IFERROR(I2,"NOT FOUND"))
```

(which is also copied down to row 13)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It seems to work pretty fine. I was wondering if it is possible to have a single formula that contains both ranges without repeat the whole formula twice?' and using the same logic, that is, search first in database1 and if not found search in database2. I was thinking in put both databases in same column with DB1 above DB2, but not sure if the formula begins the search from Row1 to RowN

Comment: @RasecMalkic - if the D3:E30 range were moved to the A14:B41 range then the formula `=INDEX($A$3:$A$41,MEDIAN(IFERROR(FIND(TRANSPOSE(MID(G2,1,LEN(G2)+4-ROW(A$4:INDEX(A:A,LEN(G2))))),$B$3:$B$41,1)*(ROW($B$3:$B$41)-2),"")))` (in row 2) would produce the same results (although you'd have to wrap it in IFERROR() to yield the _NOT FOUND_ result) - if that is something you _really_ want, i.e. with the status quo you know which DB is providing each result, but you lose that detail if you seek to aggregate the DBs...

Comment: 2 more questions to understand your formula. If range is from A2:An, how would change the formula? And since I need to find about 3000 values from a database of about 5000 rows, it freezes then is possible to use `INDEX(A1:A100...)` or something smaller instead of `INDEX(A:A...)`?

Comment: @RasecMalkic - starting in A2 with 5,000 rows the formula would be `=INDEX($A$2:$A$5001,MEDIAN(IFERROR(FIND(TRANSPOSE(MID(G2,1,LEN(G2)+4-ROW(A$4:INDEX(A:A,LEN(G2))))),$B$2:$B$5001,1)*(ROW($B$2:$B$5001)-1),"")))` the `-2` becomes a `-1` because now there is only 1 header row. Yes, you could use `INDEX(A1:A100)` instead of `INDEX(A:A)` but since the latter version doesn't actually _calculate_ 1m+ results, I don't believe it will make any difference.

Comment: @RasecMalkic Because the original question concerned 2 independent ranges, without _any_ duplicated numbers between them, the solution I posted did not consider duplicates, such that it fails when there _are_ duplicates. Accordingly, the following shorter and more efficient array formula can be used
`=INDEX($A$3:$A$41,LOOKUP(1e7,MATCH(MID(G2,1,ROW($A$4:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(G2))))&"*",$B$3:$B$41,0)))` - 1e7 is just 10m and can be used in all cases as it is greater than the number of worksheet rows (in your context 5001 _could_ be used instead, as it is larger than the 'row' of your last item)